# Image should zoom out when it is pressed and vice-versa it should go to its original postion when pressed back. in android atudio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

So,basically this is mainpage.xml code .I have cooperated so many images in this.Perhaps I want ...Whenever I will click on one of the image it will zoom out ...and same goes with other images too. Suppose I will click on Img1 so it should zoom out to full screen as of my android and when I will press back it should go to its original size.I am bemused how exactly should I execute this query.Any help is highly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainpage"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".mainpage">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/Pink"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView"
                android:layout_width="950dp"
                android:layout_height="550dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:alpha="0.5"
                android:background="@color/purple_200"
                android:text="     BEGINNERS CALLIGRAPHY"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/DarkBlue"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />


            <Button
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="210dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                android:text="PHOTOS"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:textColor="@color/purple_700"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="52dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                android:text="VIDEOS"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:textColor="@color/purple_700"/>


        </RelativeLayout>



        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="949dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:rowCount="3">

            <!-- Row 1 -->

            <!-- Column 1 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                android:background="@color/Purple">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="149dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="180dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b1" />


                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <!-- Column 2 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="180dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b2" />


                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


            <!-- Row 2 -->

            <!-- Column 1 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="149dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="180dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b3" />



                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <!-- Column 2 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="149dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="190dp"
                        android:layout_height="180dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b4" />



                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


            <!-- Row 2 -->

            <!-- Column 1 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="149dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b5" />



                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <!-- Column 2 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="149dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="180dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b6" />



                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="149dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="180dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b7" />



                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="149dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="180dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b8" />



                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="149dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b10" />



                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="130dp"
                        android:layout_height="180dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b11" />



                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="149dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="180dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b12" />



                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="149dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="180dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b1" />



                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

as I understand you have multiple images in a grid, and whenever you click on image1 it should resize to large that is zoom in, and when you are done seeing the image you want it in normal grid size on back press. if this is the sinario then you should use ZoomImageView insted of normal image view you can get ZoomImageView lib from Github . on click of this ZoomImageView set zoom ratio and on back press check if it zoomed or not.
you also use alert dialog. on click open that image in alert dialog n put zoom ZoomImageView in alert view so on click particular image gets bigger and you also can zoom it further

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).